# Capture (distinct) Print / Cancel Print Button Event (click)

Tags: javascript, events, button, printing, click

How can I capture only the cancel event from the print page?

I have a page that on a button click you have a new tab opened with print loaded, there if you click cancel (not print) I have to call a method. Same for print.

In case of print a want to execute PrintSuccesfully(), if Cancel print I want to execute PrintCancelled().

My code that opens the new tab:

```
var windowObject = window.open('', '_blank');
windowObject.document.write(generatePrintHTMLBody(scope));
windowObject.document.close();
windowObject.focus();
windowObject.print();
windowObject.close();
```

I looked up onbeforeprint and onafterprint, but both are executed with matchMedia, on CTRL+P event or on my code at Print / Cancel button click.

The code I tested was included in the generatePrintHTMLBody(scope) found [here](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/):

```
(function() {
    var beforePrint = function() {
        console.log('Functionality to run before printing.');
    };
    var afterPrint = function() {
        console.log('Functionality to run after printing');
    };

    if (window.matchMedia) {
        var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
        mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
            if (mql.matches) {
                beforePrint();
            } else {
                afterPrint();
            }
        });
    }

    window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
    window.onafterprint = afterPrint;
}());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research it seems you cannot do this... The behaviour si diferent for the buttons on each browser or it has the same signature, so no resolution exists.

Comment: and we are all okay with that ??? it's almost 2021 and I can't know which button my user is clicking.. I think we can do better then that.

Comment: another year passed, and we're still stuck on that :-(